how i can make a calling app able to select as default phone app in Android 13 or greater
I am building a calling application in flutter and want to achieve that my app would be available in default phone app list.
Till android 12 my app is in default phone app list but from android 13 , it's not in default phone list.
i followed Build a default phone application  android authentic document and to make as default dialer i added code  in manifest
     <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
           <data android:scheme="tel" />
      </intent-filter>

and also i tried  with 
i tried :
     <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
           <data android:scheme="tel" />
      </intent-filter>

and
     <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
           <data android:scheme="tel" />
      </intent-filter>


You don't need two <intent-filter> attributes, just one should be fine

You forgot the MANAGE_OWN_CALLS permission, as mentioned here

@gtxtreme i have already given MANAGE_OWN_CALLS permission and also tried single <intent-filter>  and the main problem is, above code is working till android 12 and after 12 not

I tent to use Koler, as a dialer, which is a completely native app. You can check the Manifest here. Maybe adding the exact flags will help

@gtxtreme i tried all call related permissions what manifest mentioned above but not getting app in default phone dialer in android 13 or grater
